# BitBake SRC_URI with + in the filename

Tags: openembedded, bitbake

I have a recipe that requires downloading a file with a + in the file name.  It fetches and unpacks the file to a path matching the file name, as one would expect, but then attempts to work out of a directory without the +... extension.  For example:

```
# in the xsd recipe
SRC_URI="http://www.codesynthesis.com/download/xsd/3.3/xsd-3.3.0-2+dep.tar.bz2"
```

Then `bitbake xsd` results in the following two directories:

```
xsd-3.3.0-2       (aka, ${S} according to bitbake)
xsd-3.3.0-2+dep   (where the files actually are)
```

So far I've attempted to change the `S` variable after the unpack task occurs:

```
do_unpack_append () {
    S=${S}+dep
}
```

This results in an error that the line in the function cannot be parsed.

Does anyone know of a way around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a great deal of searching, the trick was to update the S variable from within the recipe (i.e., not a task function):

```
S .= "+dep"
```

After a `-c cleanall`, BitBake fetched, decompressed, and then began working out of the corrected source path.